# Events vs boost::function

Tags: c++, events, boost

Since code speaks better than words, would you use this:

```
struct StringEvent
{
    const void* source;
    const std::string str;

    StringEvent(const void* source, const std::string& str)
        : source(source), str(str) 
    { }
};

class StringEventListener
{
public:
    virtual void handler(const StringEvent& event) = 0;
}

class Test : public StringEventListener
{
public:
    void handler(const StringEvent& event) 
    { 
        std::cout << event.str << std::endl; 
    }
}

class EventSource
{
public:
    EventSource(StringEventListener* listener) 
    { 
        listener->handler(StringEvent(this, std::string("foo"))); 
    } 
}

int main()
{
    Test test;

    EventSource(&test);
}
```

over this?

```
class Test 
{
public:
    void handler(const std::string& str) 
    { 
        std::cout << str << std::endl; 
    }
};

class EventSource
{
public:
    EventSource(const boost::function<void (const std::string&)>& funcPtr)
    {
        funcPtr(std::string("foo"));
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;

    EventSource(boost::bind(&Test::handler, &test, _1));
}
```

to make the class EventSource call `test.handler("foo")`?

Coming from the Java/C# world I find the first approach more intuitive, albeit verbose, but is it reccomanded to use in real-life situations, or does it cause more problems than it's worth/performance hits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would absolutely not use the first version. That's terrible. The second version is far superior- it can be lambdas and whatnot as well.

Also, `boost::function` is not a function pointer.

Comment: +1 -For an answer without hesitation that i agree with)

Comment: Would you please care to elaborate why the first approach would be terrible?

Comment: You're wasting your life defining an infinity of new classes *that all do the same thing*. Instead, you could just not define a class at all and use a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can use 'functors' (Objects with static methods) with Boost/C++ than the full blown object to hold callback data, and a callback object (in your former example).

It's a matter of style, and if you need objects to pass data around.

Comment: Functors are not objects with static methods. Functors are objects with `operator()`.

Comment: Where can I learn more about your definition of Functor?

Comment: http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/Stdlib/Functors.aspx